# How can I draw a line between two objects in editor mode and runtime mode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Tried this :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class DistanceCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objTarget;
    public string transformPosition;
    public string targetPosition;
    public string distance;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        transformPosition = "transform position " + transform.position;
        targetPosition = "target position " + objTarget.transform.position;
        var dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, objTarget.transform.position);
        distance = " Distance = " + dist;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, objTarget.transform.position);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

I'm using the [ExecuteAlways] so it does running the code in the Start in the editor mode and runtime mode but not drawing the line. before using Debug.DrawLine I tried to use Gizmos :

```
Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, objTarget.transform.position);
```

but either using Gizmos or Debug it's not drawing/showing the line not in the editor mode and not in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Line Renderer like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DistanceCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject object1;
    public GameObject object2;

    private void Start()
    {
        DrawLine(object1.transform.position, object2.transform.position, Color.blue);
    }

    private void DrawLine(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Color color)
    {
        GameObject line = new GameObject();
        line.transform.position = start;
        line.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        LineRenderer renderer = line.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        renderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
        renderer.material.SetColor("_Color", color);
        renderer.startWidth = 0.1f;
        renderer.endWidth = 0.1f;
        renderer.SetPosition(0, start);
        renderer.SetPosition(1, end);
    }
}
```